# iMac 27-inch making a beep every 5 seconds

Tags: imac, memory

Googling says, having a beep every 5 seconds is related to RAM.
I didn't do any replacement or upgrading of RAM.
I just restarted iMac and then it stuck in apple screen, then I forced power off.
And as result, I started having that beep.

I had 4 memories 8GB each, so trying each one by one didn't make difference.

Then I tried 4GB memory (attached image) from my old macbook pro, but this didn't help either. Or it could be not compatible.

With the information above, any ideas what when wrong?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which model of 27” iMac. There have been several versions released over the years.

Comment: @IconDaemon It's either late 2013 or 2014. I remember I purchased in 2014.